# Is there a mount storage item in D&D 4th edition?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, mount

My character has two mounts, a blade Spider and a Griffon, that I use depending on the occasion. Some times I use one, some times I use the other. My DM doesn´t complain much about that, but it´s kind of ridiculous having two mounts at once.

I use the benefits of the mounts during combat, so it would be good if I had easy access to them at all time.

I was wondering if there is an Item that works like a Pokeball, something in which I can store my mounts and carry them around easily. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Poké Ball-like item?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/40738/how-to-create-a-poke-ball-like-item)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At it's core, D&D is only bound by your imagination. The rules are truly only guidelines. There is nothing in the world that will stop you from creating item, monsters, or anything else you want. Bring it up with the dungeon master and express the need for it. This type of item seems simple enough to adapt to a D&D fantasy setting. It could be a flask the contains a pocket universe that keeps your mounts/companions health or places them into a stasis, keeping them from aging or becoming sick. You could have it set with a power word to deploy/retrieve the animal. That is what I would suggest.

> **Daern's Mount Flask - Level 15**
>
> This item stores one mount or animal companion inside. While inside the creature experiences a loving habitat where it rests and feeds. To place a creature in or call it from the flask the command word must be spoken. the command word varies from flask to flask and is engraved on the exterior of the flask.
>
> You can deploy or retrieve mount as a free action.
>
> 25,000 gp. Craft- Silver Flask, Astral Diamond, 500 xp.

Answer (score 3):

**There isn't really an item that fits this criteria**

Bag of Holding comes close, but it  misses the mark.

> Bag of Holding Level 5 Uncommon
>
> This item appears to be a simple sack of brown canvas.
>
> Wondrous Item        1,000 gp
>   Property
>
> This bag can hold up to 200 pounds in weight or 20 cubic feet in volume, but it always weighs only 1 pound.
>       Drawing an item from the bag is a minor action.

But at the end of the day its a bag and you probably couldn't carry around a bag with an opening big enough to let out a mount sized creature. One creature might fit inside the dimensions of the bag, but getting it in and out is the issue.

Comment: @DFreeman it was removed because I flagged it as non-constructive since the question is clearly tagged at 4e and you're quoteing 3.5 in a comment. Also, I'm not suggesting he use the bag of holding, in fact I'm saying not to. We regularly delete comments, they are meant to constructively help write answers and questions. If you think neither myself nor Trevor Goodchild has written a sufficiently good answer, write one yourself.

Comment: @DFreeman for more info on the comments policy see our help section: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Your answer doesn't read to me as 'No', to me it reads 'Kind of, maybe, I guess, if...'.  
Despite the fact that the answer remains the same, here then is a similar question with 4e references: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8158/can-you-place-something-living-in-a-bag-of-holding.