# How to create a Poké Ball-like item?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, homebrew, mount

My character has two magic mounts (a griffin and a bladespider). During combat he relies on the special powers granted by them when mounted. But it's kind of funny having two mounts at a time, and there are some times when it's just too strange to enter a place on a griffin or a bladespider.

I was hoping to find an item that would allow me to store my mounts and use them whenever I wanted to.

I found out from my other question ([Is there a mount storage item in D&D 4th edition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/40724/)) that there is not such an item. I don't want to use a Bag of Holding, because it would kill the mounts and also because it's a level 5 item (too low for such a powerful item).

**How do I create an item that allows me to store and access my mounts, so I can switch between them mid-combat?**

I need the item level and its limitations. Would it be a daily power? What kind of action would it use?

It would also be nice to have the item's description. Maybe a jar that shrinks the mount and let me carry it around. It could be a consumable. I could shrink the mount and then break the jar if I want to use it again. But, then, what would be the price for that?

We take turns with DM duties. All DMs agree to custom powers and rules. We have very specific rules for items that relay on the item's level. So my character level does not matter, the import thing is having a balanced item. If it's a level 30 item, my char would have to wait to get it, and it's ok. My char is currently at level 12. According to our rules, the highest item I can have is a level 16 item. It would be nice to have a item around level 16, but I would be glad to know your honest opinion, regardless if my character will be able to use the item now or later.

Comment: Rather than having two questions of "is there a pokeball item?" and "how can I make a pokeball item?", it might be worthwhile just editing _this_ one to be: "How can I store my mount away?" That is probably a lot better, since it doesn't assume it necessarily involves _items_ at all - it could use feats, rituals, non-pokeball items, or other available mechanics. (The other could be closed as a duplicate of this one, which is not a bad thing.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you absolutely must have these creatures in combat and only in combat, then your only option is to turn them into figurines of wondrous power like the [Bronze Griffin](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=817) (level 19) and the [bloodstone spider](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=716) (level 11) Note well, your blade spider has errata applied to it, so it may not be as useful as you think it is. They exist at every level (therefore, have them priced at the level of the creatures) with the text:

> "Power (Conjuration)  Daily (Standard Action)
>   Use this figurine to conjure a [creature] (see below for statistics). As a free action, you can spend a healing surge when activating this item to give the creature temporary hit points equal to your healing surge value."

Just note that their hitpoints should be significantly lower than a "real" creature's, to reflect their eternal nature.

The [reduce beast](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=379) ritual (level 7, Dragon 405) is *almost* what you're looking for, but as the beast takes a few turns to grow, it's not appropriate for in-combat use. It is reasonable to house rule a paragon tier version of it that works with literal pokeballs. Note that most rituals are designed to not be combat appropriate, so make sure there's a significant cost involved with this.

Beyond that, I'd recommend rituals for swapping things out before you go into a dungeon.

There are many options that exist for Arcane familiars, like the [Safe Retreat](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2377) (level 15), unfortunately, they don't work particularly well for more... "real" things.

I would use the [Primal Grove](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=288), not least because it's one of my favourite rituals for moving armies around.

The primal grove ritual (Level 19, primal power) creates a persistent extradimensional space:

> A grove generates enough food and drink to sustain its occupants and has a moderate, unchanging climate. If you move objects into a grove, they remain there when you leave,

So it's a great place to keep people. With 10 minutes (or fewer if you specialise) and 4k (which at the levels you're talking about is literally pocket change). The 10 minute casting time is handy because you can't pull it out during battle, which means it doesn't need to be balanced for battle.

Alternatively, if you read the hireling rules liberally, it seems to be viable to have a level-appropriate hireling (cost * 3 equivalent to sage) be able to cast specific rituals.

What you'll need, therefore, are 3 pairs of [sending stones](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2429) (level 11) and 2 ritualist casters. The [follow the voice](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=332) ritual (level 16) allows the caster to teleport to the location of the last activated stone:

> You fold yourself and each ally you choose who is within 3 squares of you through a sending stone you hold.

The real trick is that there's a 24 hour use limit on pairs of stones and casters.

Therefore, there are two operations that you'll be performing: "sending" and "receiving" The sending operation has one pair speak to you through one of your personal stones, the first one casts follow the voice, teleports himself, his buddy, and your ally to you. They drop off the ally, collect whomever needs collecting, and the casting buddy returns.

The third pair of stones is for your fellow PCs. Sometimes, you'll want to teleport an injured companion back, and you'll need to home in on a PC's stone instead.

Comment: @user3347814 The reason you didn't get as good answers on the other question is that you didn't make it clear you wanted *in-combat* switching; it wasn't until I realised that and edited into your question here that Brian was able to give you solid suggestions for existing mechanics.

Comment: I liked the reduce beast ritual alternative. That is almost exactly what I was looking for. But I would like to turn that into a item, instead of a ritual. Should I start another tread to discuss how that item should be?

Comment: We don't do "threads" here. Take a look at our [about].   I would revise *this* question, as you already have your previous question as a duplicate of this one. (I recommend deleting that one.) Edit this question such that it asks what you want it to ask. Or, edit this question for "what rituals provide portable companions" and make a simple question of "how to invest a ritual into an item."

Answer (score 1):

If your group (and DM) is okay with cutoms rules and items, why not create a few custom [Figurines of Wondrous Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/figurines-of-wondrous-power)?

They could easily be used in combat because they only require a spoken command word to activate. If the creature dies, it just reverts to its figurine form; kind of like fainting and returning to a pokeball.